# How can I recover previous data from recursion?

Tags: c++, c, recursion

I have a small program below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

void changeArray(int *a, int n)
{
    swap(a[rand() % n], a[rand() % n]);
}

void Try(int* a, int n, int step)
{
    if (step > n)
        return;

    changeArray(a, n);
    Try(a, n, step + 1);
    //Do something to recovery previous array data?
}

void printArr(int *a, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int step = 0;
    int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int);
    printArr(a, n); //Before
    Try(a, n, 0);
    printArr(a, n); //After recursion
    // Expected array is : 1,2,3,4,5

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is a as follows: can I recover previously created data? Line 17 will recover an array after `Try()` function is run on line 16.
The resulting, line 36, array will be 1,2,3,4,5.
Any ideas would be really appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem. The function `changeArray` randomly swap the array elements. How can you recover the data after random swapping?

Comment: Oh. changeArray() function is a small example of function that change value of array.
I try to solve Travelling Salesman Problem, in that I have function that change value of matrix, then call Try(rightNode). And I want to recovery data before call Try(leftNode).

Like that:

Try()
{
   TSPNode* leftNode, *rightNode;
   changeMatrix(matrix);
   Try(rightNode);
   //Recover data here
   Try(leftNode);
}

Comment: I have a solution.
http://ideone.com/jnzmAD
But It consume so much memory.

Comment: oh 
1: You can use a structure 1 key to save index of value example.
2: Save array to file and re read it :) (Use more loop) 
3: Save array to array Temp (use more memory). 
4: Save recover index before change array, and recall return index after function ended.

Comment: Thank you for your listing solutions. 
Can you describe solution 1 more clearly.